# Dual of braiding in symmetric monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, duality-theorems, monoidal-categories

Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,1)$ be a symmetric monoidal category with symmetry $\gamma$.
Assume $X,Y\in\mathcal{C}$ are a dual pair in the sense that there exist evaluation and coevaluation morphisms $ev\colon X\otimes Y\to 1$ and $in\colon 1\to Y\otimes X$ such that
$$
X\stackrel{X\otimes in}{\to}X\otimes Y\otimes X\stackrel{ev\otimes X}{\to} X=id_X\\
Y\stackrel{in\otimes Y}{\to}Y\otimes X\otimes Y\stackrel{Y\otimes ev}{\to} Y=id_Y
$$
(omitting associator and unitor isomorphisms).

In a situation where $X,Y$ and $X',Y'$ are dual pairs, we can define the dual of a morphism $f\colon X\to X'$ as $$f^\ast\colon Y'\stackrel{in\otimes Y'}{\to} Y\otimes X\otimes Y'\ \stackrel{Y\otimes f\otimes Y}{\to}Y\otimes X'\otimes Y' \stackrel{Y\otimes ev'}{\to} Y.$$

Now note that if $X,Y$ is a dual pair as defined above, $X\otimes X,Y\otimes Y$ will become a dual pair with coevaluation given by $in\colon 1\stackrel{in}{\to}Y\otimes X\stackrel{Y\otimes in\otimes X}{\to}Y\otimes Y\otimes X\otimes X$ and similarly for evaluation.

But now we can look at the symmetry/braiding $\gamma_{X,X}\colon X\otimes X\to X\otimes X$ and its dual morphism $\gamma_{X,X}^\ast \colon Y\otimes Y\to Y\otimes Y$.

My question is: *Is $\gamma_{X,X}^\ast$ equal to the braiding $\gamma_{Y,Y}$?*

For all similar questions I have been able to answer them myself by just composing commutative diagrams from the axioms. But here, we have almost no information; in particular, the definition of dual pairs does not involve symmetry, so the only information we have about the braiding $\gamma_{Y,Y}$ and the map $\gamma_{X,X}^\ast$ comes from the axioms for a symmetric monoidal category, which doesn't tell us much.
So, I am open to be convinced that the answer is no, but have been unable to produce a counterexample, I would be also very grateful for that.